# Using pubnub with parse.com for in-app chat

Tags: android, parse-platform, pubnub

I'm building an android app which uses parse.com as the backend. Every user of the app logs in through fb and the user profile info is stored in the parse user table. On clicking a certain button the app provides the user with a list of parse users who are in the vicinity in a listview i.e each item in the list view is a parse user. Something like this:

```
ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseUser> factory= new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseUser>(){
        @Override
        public ParseQuery<ParseUser> create() {
            user = ParseUser.getQuery();
            user.whereNear("source",mySrc);
            user.whereEqualTo("destination", dest);
            user.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", currentUser.getObjectId());
            user.setLimit(MAX_SEARCH_RESULTS);
            return user;
          }
    };  
    // Set up the query adapter
     parseAdapter= new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseUser>(this, factory){
      @Override
      public View getItemView(ParseUser user, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null) {
          view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.listtextview, null);                       
        }
        super.getItemView(user,view,parent);
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);            
        name.setText(user.getString("name"));             
          return view;
      }
    };
```

Now this is what i want to do:
When the user clicks on any one of the items in the list a chat window should open and the two users should be able to chat. I believe pubnub can be used for this purpose as in for in-app chat if i haven't got it wrong in my head.
How can i achieve the same using pubnub?

I have thought of an approach:
Every user will have a channel that he/she subscribes to automatically when they log in for the first time and this channel name will be stored in the parse user table.
When the user selects an item from the list view the app subscribes him/her to the channel of the corresponding user.
However i can figure out how i will manage/assign channel names in this approach?
Shouldn't the channel name be unique for every user?
Can i use the user's fb id itself as the channel name?

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: I am also implementing same features in my android application.I am able to one to one chat.But trying for group chat.You can follow parse.com android tutorial.

Comment: @jagdish Hey thats exactly what i want to do in my app: Just one to one chat, can you be more specific and help me out here!! I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I followed the tutorial https://parse.com/docs/android_guide. Please try it let me know.

Comment: @user3129550 You can use the PubNub iOS and Android SDKs for implementing the in-app chat functionality your require. Your UI code doesn't change, you just need to wire up the publish/subscribe calls as required by your app. If you need further assistance with integrating PubNub into your application, just contact their support: support.pubnub.com